# getChildHtml() method not working in product list page (category view.phtml/ product list.phtml) in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.6

I am calling my newly created reference in list.phtml file after getToolbarHtml(). But it is not displaying anything. My catalog.xml file looks something like:

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>

                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>9</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>2</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>4</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>6</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <reference name="newreference">
                        <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml" />
                    </reference>

                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>

                </block>
                    </block>
```

I am calling reference inside of reference, the thing is i want to create my own sidebar. So what is wrong with it? In list.phtml I am calling my reference by:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?>
```

Please, Help me.

Comment: have you created newreference in your system, basically it is wrong to call one reference in another reference

Comment: Yes, I have created it in the **page.xml** file.

Answer (score 5):

Please use the below method (Remember to update your xml inside catelog.xml under content):

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->getBlock('yourblockname')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace:

```
<reference name="newreference">
    <block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml" />
</reference>
```

with:

```
<block type="core/template" name="newreferenceblock" template="newreference.phtml" />
```

and then call your block inside template using 'newreferenceblock' as a name of the block:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreferenceblock') ?>
```

Comment: Nupp @zitix, its not working for me ... :(. Actually I want to call the reference from list.phtml.

Comment: But why you put <reference> inside <reference>? Post more code, it's difficult to figure out what exactly you want to do.

Comment: Issue solved, yeah that was mistake too, I removed the reference from there to outside. Now its working fine. :), btw, thanx for your time @zitix ..!! :)

Comment: No problem. :) You can edit your post to show the correct final code, it may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Put your newreference block out side of your content block.

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?> call this block in one of your layout file something like below its for 2columns-right layout

<div class="main-container col2-right-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <div class="col-main">
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>
        </div>
        <div><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreference') ?></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Yeah that is working completely fine, but the thing is, I want to display my reference **newreference** below the toolbar/pager, so I need to call it under content block.

Comment: ok so you don't need to create newreference for your requirement just call your block under toolbar block and remove your newreference tag and in list.phtml file after toolbar block `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('newreferenceblock') ?>` put this code and you are done

Comment: I have done that but it is not working. And I have to do this because I need to call some other blocks in left sidebar, so I am trying to create my own left sidebar reference and along with that I want to display pager/toolbar in place of breadcrumbs.

Comment: If you are willing to display in left sidebar then how thing is display under toolbar section because toolbar is in content area?

Comment: Yes, Toolbar is in the content area. I want to show toolbar in place of breadcrumbs. Than I want to show left sidebar under toolbar and besides left sidebar, in content area, I want to display the product listing. That is my target.

Comment: See, I want my category view page to be looked like, first logo and category menu, than in main area, first, I want to display toolbar-pager (no breadcrumbs). Than I want to display rest content (left side bar and grid/list of products). Now you got that @Mufaddal ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
                <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">

                     <block type="core/text_list" name="left_custompage" as="left_custompage">
                        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
                     </block>
                    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                        <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        <!-- The following code shows how to set your own pager increments -->
                        <!--
                            <action method="setDefaultListPerPage"><limit>10</limit></action>
                            <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage"><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>10</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>20</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>list</mode><limit>30</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>list</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>8</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>16</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit"><mode>grid</mode><limit>24</limit></action>
                            <action method="addPagerLimit" translate="label"><mode>grid</mode><limit>all</limit><label>All</label></action>
                        -->
                    </block>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>empty</layout><count>6</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>one_column</layout><count>5</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_left</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>two_columns_right</layout><count>4</count></action>
                    <action method="addColumnCountLayoutDepend"><layout>three_columns</layout><count>3</count></action>
                    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                </block>
            </block>
```

Where custompage is my custom block, which I am using as sidebars.